# Don't get array text, but only output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code from [get the next birthday with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264237/get-the-next-birthday-with-php) to get upcoming birthday on page with only php. The output is okay but looks like this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Tom(23-5)" }` how do I fix it that it will only show "Tom (23-5)"

```
$json = '{
    "user": [
          {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tom",
    "bday": {
          "month": "5",
          "day": "23"
          }
    },
    {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Tommy",
    "bday": {
          "month": "1",
          "day": "28"
          }
    },
    {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Mary",
    "bday": {
          "month": "1",
          "day": "30"
          }
    },
    {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Kelvin",
    "bday": {
          "month": "1",
          "day": "1"
          }
    },
    {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Peter",
    "bday": {
          "month": "1",
          "day": "1"
          }
    }

    ]
    }';
$birthday_array = json_decode($json,true);
//var_dump($bir_array);
$result = findBday($birthday_array['user']);
var_dump($result);


function findBday($user_details){
    $this_month = date("n");
    $this_day = date("j");
    $return_array = array();
    $tmp_array = array();
    //make a loop
    foreach ($user_details as $user_detail) {        
        $bday = $user_detail['bday'];
        if($this_month == $bday['month'] && $this_day == $bday['day']){
            $return_array[] = $user_detail['name'] . "(".$bday['day']."-".$bday['month'].")";
        } 
        else {
            $tmp_array[] =  $user_detail;
          }
    }
    if(count($return_array) === 0 && count($tmp_array) > 0)
    {

        //sort using php usort
        usort ($tmp_array, 'sortByOrder'); 
        $closest = null;        
        $tmp_val = "";
        foreach ($tmp_array as $key => $value) {
            $month = $value['bday']['month'];
            $day = $value['bday']['day'];
            if($month == $this_month)
            {
                if($day > $this_day){
                    $tmp_val = $value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            elseif ($month > $this_month) {
                $tmp_val = $value;
                break;
            }
        }      
        if($tmp_val != "")
            $tmp_array = $tmp_val;
        else    
            $tmp_array = $tmp_array[0];
        $bday = $tmp_array['bday'];
        $return_array[] = $tmp_array['name'] . "(".$bday['day']."-".$bday['month'].")";

    }


    return $return_array;
}
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {    
    $day_a = $a['bday'];
    $day_b = $b['bday'];
    if ($day_a['month'] > $day_b['month'])
        return 1;
    elseif($day_a['month'] == $day_b['month'])
    {
        if ($day_a['day'] > $day_b['day'])   
            return 1;
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping me. I didn't find the answer on the post that was posted on the page I added. So I would like to get an answer here. I'm relatively new to this coding, so therefore my question.

Comment: Use `return $return_array[0]` instead of `return $return_array`

Comment: Or even better, just return `$tmp_array['name'] . "(".$bday['day']."-".$bday['month'].")"` directly. Don't build an array to return if you don't actually need an array.

Comment: I put  "echo $return_array[0];" , but now it shows "Tom 25-5NULL", what did I do wrong now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the result is an array. If you just want the first name, then read the first entry of the array:

```
$nextBirthday = $result[0];
```

If you want `$result` to be just the name, then change the return statement of your `findBday` function to `return $return_array[0]`.

Comment: Why even create an array to return from if all you want is its element?

Comment: I wasn't sure how many entries the array can contain, so I showed how to get the first element. But yes, returning an array with only one element inside doesn't make sense, that's why I added the line below where I showed how to change the return statement.